# SQL Query execution using Python and post on HTTP endpoint

Tags: python-2.7

I have written a small program which will run SQL query and XPOST the results on an HTTP endpoint. My future task is to run multiple queries using this script, I will putting them in a text file and use file handlers in the code. Kindly let me know if my program seems to be correct for the small requirement I have.

```
#Script to run the SQL query and store the output in a text file as per line 

protocol.
#Author Author1
import pyodbc
#import urllib.request
#import sys
#print(sys.prefix)
#print(sys.version)
import subprocess

cnxn =  pyodbc.connect('DSN=DSN;UID=user1;PWD=pwd')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""SELECT 'service', 'status=' + CAST([Status] AS 
VARCHAR)
 ,'status_name=' + CASE [STATUS]
      WHEN 2 THEN 'Ready'
      WHEN 3 THEN 'Processing'
      WHEN 99 THEN 'Error'
 ELSE CAST([STATUS] AS VARCHAR) END
 ,'count=' + CAST(COUNT(*) AS VARCHAR)
 ,'avg_sec=' + CAST(AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND,[STOREDON],GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR)
 ,'min_sec=' + CAST(MIN(DATEDIFF(SECOND,[STOREDON],GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR)
 ,'max_sec=' + CAST(MAX(DATEDIFF(SECOND,[STOREDON],GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR)
 ,'timestamp=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 121)
FROM [DB1].[LN_CDCLOCKS] (NOLOCK)
WHERE [STATUS] <> 0
AND [STOREDON] > DATEADD(MINUTE,-15,GETDATE())
GROUP BY [STATUS]
""")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
print(service, row.status_name, row.status, row.count, 
row.avg_sec)
command = 'curl -i -XPOST -u user:pwd 
"http://influx.abc.com:8086/write?db=mort" --data-
binary'
subprocess.Popen(command, service, 
service_name=row.status_name, count=row.count, avg_sec=row.avg_sec, 
min_sec=row.min_sec, max_sec=row.max_sec)
#err = p.communicate()ode here
```